# Scroll button scrolls to multiple elements position

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a single button that scrolls to multiple elements position in `jquery`.

Let's say I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>This is div one.</div>
  <div>This is div two.</div>
  <div>This is div three.</div>
  <div>This is div four.</div>
  <div>This is div five.</div>
</div>
```

I can create an event in `jquery` like this one:

```
$('button#divone').click(function(){
  $('body').scrollTop(/*Element pos*/);
});
```

But, that means I have to create a button for each div and also a `jquery` event for each one.

Is there any better way?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_to_top

Comment: Use class not an id for this perhaps?  Next, question - how do you wish to differentiate WHICH you wish to scroll to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var scrolled = 1;
  /*If you want it to start from the first div set the value to 0;*/
  
  var elements = $('div.container').find('div').length;
  
  /*Scroll Down button*/
  $('button#scrollbtn_D').click(function(){
    
    var pos = $('div.container div').eq(scrolled).offset().top;
      
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: pos},
    'slow');
      
    scrolled += 1;
    
    if(scrolled>=elements){
      $(this).hide();
    }
    
    $('button#scrollbtn_U').show();
  
  });
  
  /*Scroll Up button*/
  $('button#scrollbtn_U').click(function(){
    scrolled -= 2;
    var pos = $('div.container div').eq(scrolled).offset().top;

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: pos},
    'slow');
    
    scrolled += 1;
    
    if(scrolled==1){
      $(this).hide();
    }
    
    $('button#scrollbtn_D').show();
  
  });
  
  $('button#scrollbtn_U').hide();
  
});
```

```css
div.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
div.container div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
button#scrollbtn_D{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  left:340px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button#scrollbtn_U{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  left:395px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div>This is div one.</div>
  <div>This is div two.</div>
  <div>This is div three.</div>
  <div>This is div four.</div>
  <div>This is div five.</div>

</div>
<button id="scrollbtn_D">Down</button>
<button id="scrollbtn_U">Up</button>
```

Comment: What you have works - I wonder if you might also add an "up" button to allow an up/down - that would make it nice (although this DOES work given the limited description by the OP)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to scroll to an element.

```
 function scrollTo(elem){
   $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: elem.offset().top
   }, 2000);
 }
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 2000px;
} 

div.block{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Scroll To Div Number (1-11):
<input type="number" id="num"/><p/>
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll</button>
<div class = "block" id="1">
1
</div>
<div class = "block" id="2">
2
</div>
<div class = "block" id="3">
3
</div>
<div class = "block" id="4">
4
</div>
<div class = "block" id="5">
5
</div>
<div class = "block" id="6">
6
</div>
<div class = "block" id="7">
7
</div>
<div class = "block" id="8">
8
</div>
<div class = "block" id="9">
9
</div>
<div class = "block" id="10">
10
</div>
<div class="block" id="11">
11
</div>
<script>
function scrollTo(elem){
       $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: elem.offset().top
       }, 2000);
}
function scrollToDiv(){
  var num = $('#num').val();
  if(num.trim().length&&parseFloat(num)>0&&parseFloat(num)<12&&document.getElementById(num)){
  scrollTo($('#'+num));
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: click and see ""message": "TypeError: elem.offset(...) is undefined","

Comment: Note this also allows -2 selection etc. which throws an error

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss That will only happen when value entered is not from 1-11. I will change it. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: @AhmadSalameh Thanks for telling me. I have adding checking if the element with the `id` exists.